# How to show/hide navbar item based on custom decorator admin role

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, navbar, flask-login

decorators.py

```
from functools import wraps

from flask import flash, redirect, url_for
from flask_login import current_user


def admin_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if current_user.role == "Admin":
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash("You need to be an admin to view this page.")
            return redirect(url_for('account'))

    return wrap
```

I'm able to hide/show navbar items in jinja using current_user.is_authenticated, but I can't seem to get it to work with using the role of the user. Does anyone know how I can alter navbar items in my base template based on the role of a user?

base.html

```
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                {{ render_nav_item('account', 'Account', use_li=True) }}
                {{ render_nav_item('logout', 'Logout', use_li=True) }}
              {% elif current_user.role == "Admin" %}
                {{ render_nav_item('admin_panel', 'Admin Panel', use_li=True) }}
              {% else %}
                {{ render_nav_item('login', 'Login', use_li=True) }}
              {% endif %}

            </div>
```

models.py

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    weekly_time = db.relationship('WeeklyTime', backref=db.backref('user'), lazy=True)
    weekly_expense = db.relationship('WeeklyExpense', backref=db.backref('user'), lazy=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    account_creation_datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

    role = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    confirmed_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    password_reset_token = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.name}', '{self.email}')"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is and Admin role authenticated? That is, does `if current_user.is_authenticated` evaluate to `True` for an Admin role? In that case your `if` statement terminates on the first condition. You need a separate `if` condition to test if an authenticated user is an Admin.

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ render_nav_item('account', 'Account', use_li=True) }}
    {{ render_nav_item('logout', 'Logout', use_li=True) }}
    {% if current_user.role == "Admin" %}
        {{ render_nav_item('admin_panel', 'Admin Panel', use_li=True) }}
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {{ render_nav_item('login', 'Login', use_li=True) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: LOL. Oh my god, yes the admin role is authenticated. What a simple mistake that I have overlooked for a week. 
I will try this solution tonight and let you know if it works. Thank you.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare two topbar, top and top2 in your application app.py:

```
...

from flask_login import UserMixin, LoginManager, login_required, current_user, login_user, logout_user
...

nav = Nav()

# registers the "top" menubar
nav.register_element('top', Navbar(logo,
                                   View('Home', 'index'),                                   
                                   View('LogIn', 'login'),  # login
                                   View('SignUp', 'signup'),  # signup
                                   ))
# registers the "top2" menubar
nav.register_element('top2', Navbar(logo,
                                    View('Home', 'index'),
                                    View('Profile', 'profile'),  # def profile                                    
                                    View('LogOut', 'logout'),  # def logout
                                    ))
```

and now in your base.html you can choose with if block as:

```
<body>
    {% block navbar %}
        {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
            {{nav.top2.render()}}
        {% else %} 
            {{nav.top.render()}}
        {% endif %}    
    {% endblock %}
...
</body>
```

Comment: we use a module flask-nav. "from flask_nav import Nav" and
"from flask_nav.elements import * "